# c# DataGridView update cell value

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I write code in C# that show value of List in DataGridView:

I have this list:

```
List<Order> list = new List<Order> { new Order("Fettina ai Ferri", ""), new Order("1 X", "0.99") };
```

this list shows in datagridview (ordersDtaGrid):

```
var source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = list;
ordersDtaGrid.DataSource = source;
```

It works.

[image]

Now i change a value in list:

```
list[1].name = "4 X"
```

And i would like to update datagrid:

```
var source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = list;
ordersDtaGrid.DataSource = source;
```

And this is result in datagrid:

[image]

There are both the old and the new value.

I have also try adding:

```
ordersDtaGrid.Refresh();
ordersDtaGrid.Focus();
```

but nothig.

How can i fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using `DataGridVIew` or `DataGrid` control? They are different controls where `DataGridView` is newer one. Do you have some custom drawing methods

Comment: If you make `Order` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and instead of `List` will use  `BindingList<Order>` - then you don't need to "reset" datasource every time you update some property. `BindingList` will raise an event and `DataGridView` will listen it and update view automatically

Comment: I am using DataGridView.

Comment: It is updating with new values, but the older value still behide.
In figure see '4 X' over '1 X'.
Maybe that the datagridview does not upgrade the cell content.

Comment: If I double click on cell it show the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

maybe below can be helpful:

```
list.Clear();
ordersDtaGrid.DataSource = list;
```